# Bootstrap 4 Grid xl devices

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a responsive bootstrap 4 template with the use of the grid system. Everything is crystal clear of how it works, as the documentation describes. What i can not understand is how can i, with the use of bootstrap grid, have a different layout for a device with >= 1366 pixels, which in my opinion is common breakpoint on laptops. The bootstrap grid stops at 1200 pixels with the tag col-xl-* what can i do after that? Why there is not a bigger in pixels breakpoint? What am i missing?

Thank you, in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is the answer with examples: https://www.beyondjava.net/how-to-add-a-new-breakpoint-in-bootstrap**

You can basically create your own breakpoints with modifying certain files :)

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful, and i understand that i am not missing anything, there is not such a breakpoint like >=1366px and the solution is, to create my breakpoints. But still is weird why there are not bigger breakpoints.

Comment: don't mind it, just use them as you please, you can create wathever you want. The article covers bootstrap 3 too if you need that too